# Django finding static file (1.5) ERROR 404 1649

Tags: python, css, django, web-applications

I'm really struggling to set up my Django site (local). I've read the other questions and answers, but I can't figure it out.

```
[20/Oct/2013 03:56:33] "GET /rides/ HTTP/1.1" 200 230
[20/Oct/2013 03:56:33] "GET /static/rides/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1649
```

static.css

```
    li a {
    color: green;
}
```

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'rides/style.css' %}" />
```

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

my style.css is located at

```
/Users/Marcus/Sites/Django/groupride/static/rides/style.css
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

THanks

Comment: SOLUTION: STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                    # location of your application, should not be public web accessible
                    '/Users/Marcus/Sites/Django/groupride/static',
                    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use development server to serve static, so you need to add following to your urls.py:

`(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/path/to/your/static/'}),`

Don't use this in production environment.